# Best practices for react conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, rendering, jsx

I have a div/section that should be displayed when a button is toggled

```
{
  this.state.viewButtonClicked ?  <Solution solution= {this.state.activeSolution}/> : <React.Fragment/>
}
```

Is using a ternary operator appropriate for this?

And in this case, what's the best practice to not display something if a button is false?

Is React.Fragment okay?

Basically I want to return/render null if viewButtonClicked is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes it should be fine. Additionally you can just do this

```
  {
       this.state.viewButtonClicked && <Solution solution={this.state.activeSolution}/>
  }
```

Comment: Ah cool. Was looking for this - seems to be cleaner than a Ternary returning a useless Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep using ternary operator, as follows

```
{
  this.state.viewButtonClicked ? <Solution solution={this.state.activeSolution}/> : null;
}
```

or short-circuit && operator.

```
{
  this.state.viewButtonClicked && <Solution solution={this.state.activeSolution}/>
}
```

You can read [this article](https://www.devaradise.com/react-conditional-rendering-if-else) for more details about React conditional rendering best practices with 7 different methods.